# Scroll Height Return "None" in Selenium: [ arguments[0].scrollHeight ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Working on the python Bot with selenium, and infinite scrolling in dialog box isn't working due to "None" return from the "arguments[0].scrollHeight"

```
dialogBx=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='dialog']/div[2]")

print(dialogBx)  #<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fcec89cc11fa5fa5eaf29a8efa9989f9", element="31bfd470-de78-XXXX-XXXX-ac1ffa6224c4")>
print(type(dialogBx)) #<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
sleep(5)

last_height=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollHeight",dialogBx);
print("Height : ",last_height) #None
```

I needed last height to compare, please suggest solution.

Comment: Hi can you please tell which url are you trying to get this from? @Abin Lakhanpal?

Comment: Armando it's Instagram follower dialog box

Comment: ok I have questions:
1) how are you getting the dialogBx? I have seen instagram website and that specific part is loaded or "inserted" dynamically when you click the followers buttons, so that xpath's content in only loaded when you click it. Did you already do that or what approach did you took?
2) What do you wish to achieve with the scrolling? get all the followers data?

Comment: 1) Yes, with selenium clicking on the follower and dialog box appear at runtime. 2) yes, to get list of the followers.

Comment: Sorry  I have been a little busy I will post my aswer in a moment @Abin Lakhanpal

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to answer your question, since you are inside a dialog we should focus on it. When you execute : `last_height=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollHeight",dialogBx);` I believe you are executing that  in the main page or in a wrong div (not 100% sure). Either way I took a diferente approach, we are going to select the last `<li>` item currently available in the dialog and scroll down to its position, this will force the dialog to update. I will extract a code from the full code you will see below:

```
last_li_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{p}]'.format(p=start_pos))
last_li_item.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

We first select the last list item and then the property **location_once_scrolled_into_view**. This property will scroll our dialog down to our last item and then it will load more items. start_pos is just the position in the list of `<li>` element we have available. ie.: `<div><li></li><li></li><li></li></div>` start_pos=2 which is the last li item starting from 0. I put this variable name because it is inside a for loop which is watching the changes of li items inside the div, you will get it once you see the full code.

In other hand to execute this,simply change the parameters at the top and execute the test function **test()**. If you are already log in to instagram you can just run **get_list_of_followers()**.
Note: Using this function use a Follower class that is also in this code. You can remove if you wish but you will need to modify the function.
IMPORTANT:

When you execute this program, the dialog box items will be increasing until there is no more items to load, so a TODO would be remove the element you have already processed otherwise I believe performace will get slower when you start hitting big numbers!

Let me know if you need any other explanation. Now the code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

# instagram url as our base
base_url = "https://www.instagram.com"
# =====================MODIFY THESE TO YOUR NEED=========
# the user we wish to get the followers from
base_user = "/nasa/"
# how much do you wish to sleep to wait for loading (seconds)
sleep_time = 3
# True will attempt login with facebook, False with instagram
login_with_facebook = True
# Credentials here
username = "YOUR_USERNAME"
password = "YOUR_PASSWORD"

# How many users do you wish to retrieve? -1 = all or n>0
get_users = 10
#==========================================================
# This is the div that contains all the followers info not the dialog box itself
dialog_box_xpath = '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div'

total_followers_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a/span'
followers_button_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a'
insta_username_xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input'
insta_pwd_xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input'
insta_login_button_xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button'
insta_fb_login_button_xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div[6]/button'

fb_username_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[1]/input'
fb_pwd_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/input'
fb_login_button_xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[3]/button'

u_path = fb_username_xpath if login_with_facebook else insta_username_xpath
p_path = fb_pwd_xpath if login_with_facebook else insta_pwd_xpath
lb_path = fb_login_button_xpath if login_with_facebook else insta_login_button_xpath


# Simple class of a follower, you dont actually need this but for explanation is ok.
class Follower:
    def __init__(self, user_name, href):
        self.username = user_name
        self.href = href

    @property
    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def get_href(self):
        return self.href

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.username


def test():
    base_user_path = base_url + base_user
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(base_user_path)

    # click the followers button and will ask for login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(followers_button_xpath).click()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    # now we decide if we will login with facebook or instagram
    if login_with_facebook:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(insta_fb_login_button_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    username_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u_path)
    username_input.send_keys(username)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath(p_path)
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(lb_path).click()
    # We need to wait a little longer for the page to load so. Feel free to change this to your needs.
    time.sleep(10)
    # click the followers button again
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(followers_button_xpath).click()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    # now we get the list of followers from the dialog box. This function will return a list of follower objects.
    followers: list[Follower] = get_list_of_followers(driver, dialog_box_xpath, get_users)
    # close the driver we do not need it anymore.
    driver.close()
    for follower in followers:
        print(follower, follower.get_href)


def get_list_of_followers(driver, d_xpath=dialog_box_xpath, get_items=10):
    """
    Get a list of followers from instagram
    :param driver: driver instance
    :param d_xpath: dialog box xpath. By default it gets the global parameter but you can change it
    :param get_items: how many items do you wish to obtain? -1 = Try to get all of them. Any positive number will be
    = the number of followers to obtain
    :return: list of follower objects
    """
    # getting the dialog content element
    dialog_box: WebElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(d_xpath)
    # getting all the list items (<li></li>) inside the dialog box.
    dialog_content: list[WebElement] = dialog_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    # Get the total number of followers. since we get a string we need to convert to int by int(<str>)
    total_followers = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li['
                                                       '2]/a/span').get_attribute("title").replace(".",""))
    # how many items we have without scrolling down?
    li_items = len(dialog_content)
    # We are trying to get n elements (n=get_items variable). Now we need to check if there are enough followers to
    # retrieve from if not we will get the max quantity of following. This applies only if n is >=0. If -1 then the
    # total amount of followers is n
    if get_items == -1:
        get_items = total_followers
    elif -1 < get_items <= total_followers:
        # no need to change anything, git is ok to work with get_items
        pass
    else:
        # if it not -1 and not between 0 and total followers then we raise an error
        raise IndexError

    # You can start from greater than 0 but that will give you a shorter list of followers than what you wish if
    # there is not enough followers available. i.e: total_followers = 10, get_items=10, start_from=1. This will only
    # return 9 followers not 10 even if get_items is 10.
    return generate_followers(0, get_items, total_followers, dialog_box, driver)


def generate_followers(start_pos, get_items, total_followers, dialog_box_element: WebElement, driver):
    """
    Generate followers based on the parameters
    :param start_pos: index of where to start getting the followers from
    :param get_items: total items to get
    :param total_followers = total number of followers
    :param dialog_box_element: dialog box to get the list items count
    :param driver: driver object
    :return: followers list
    """
    if -1 < start_pos < total_followers:
        # we want to count items from our current position until the last element available without scrolling. We do
        # it this way so when we scroll down, the list items will be greater but we will start generating followers
        # from our last current position not from the beginning!
        first = dialog_box_element.find_element_by_xpath("./li[{pos}]".format(pos=start_pos+1))
        li_items = dialog_box_element.find_elements_by_xpath("./li[position()={pos}][last("
                                                             ")]/following-sibling::li"
                                                             .format(pos=(start_pos + 1)))
        li_items.insert(0, first)
        print("Generating followers from position position: {pos} with {li_count} list items"
              .format(pos=(start_pos+1), li_count=len(li_items)))
        followers = []
        for i in range(len(li_items)):
            anchors = li_items[i].find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
            anchor = anchors[0] if len(anchors) ==1 else anchors[1]
            follower = Follower(anchor.text, anchor.get_attribute(
                "href"))
            followers.append(follower)
            get_items -= 1
            start_pos += 1
            print("Follower {f} added to the list".format(f=follower))
            # we break the loop if our starting position is greater than 0 or if get_items has reached 0 (means if we
            # request 10 items we got them all no need to continue
            if start_pos >= total_followers or get_items == 0:
                print("finished")
                return followers
        print("finished loop, executing scroll down...")
        last_li_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[{p}]'.format(p=start_pos))
        last_li_item.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        followers.extend(generate_followers(start_pos, get_items, total_followers, dialog_box_element, driver))
        return followers
    else:
        raise IndexError
```

Comment: Thank you armando for this code help, but My question was different. Why dialog box was not "None" as height. I checked elements, it seems fine tho'.